# Trying to install an extension via Magento Connect Manager: Extension dependencies

Tags: extensions, magento-connect, dependency

I'm not an expert with Magento, but I'm trying to install an extension via Magento Connect Manager using the key, but when I click on "Install" after few seconds appears the message "Extension dependencies". I think I miss something, but I don't really know what.

Can someone explain to me what to do?

Comment: which extension are you installing.?

Comment: I've tried different extensions, with the same result. Now I'm trying with Klevu Smart Search.

Answer (score 1):

Is the extension made for your version of magento? I find magento very fussy when installing extensions as they can often break your website, I recommend always checking the version which it supports and the reviews. I use both magento & WordPress and WordPress defiantly handles extensions better!

Comment: I've Magento Community 1.9.0.1 and every extension I tried to install was compatible. And now using Magento Connect Manager makes the site to go offline.

Comment: Magento can be a nightmare at times! Does it make your whole website go down?

Comment: Can you link me to a screenshot

Comment: I was told that there's a specific file ("maintenance..." something) that drops in the main site root and should delete itself during an upgrade or a plug-in installation. In this case the file didn't delete itself (probably because the installation with Connect Manager failed) and that was the cause of the site going down. Everytime this happen I have to manually delete the file via ftp.

Comment: Right, I see your getting the Matience Flag file.It might be worth using this tool http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php and downloading the extension files yourself and upload it via FTP, but do it at your own risk but it worked for me when I was trying to install something.